# Where is the file on my server?

Tags: php, ms-access-2007

I'm connecting to my access database using PHP.
My access file is located here in the server:

> e:\home\sbpsp2\dados\fichas\jornada_xyz.mdb

then... here is the code

```
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "dados\fichas\jornada_xyz.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

I always get "Could not find database file", already tried different things on the first line.

Comment: Did you try the full path?

Comment: Use the full path or make sure your DOCUMENT_ROOT is pointing to e:\home\sbpsp2\

Comment: document_root is whereever the start of your website is. unless you're hosting your site in `e:\home\sbpsp2\...`, then that's the wrong thing to be using.

Comment: When using double quotes, it's always a good idea to escape backslashes , imagine a path like `dados\newLine\return\alert\tab\space`...

Answer (score 3):

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
```

Does not mean your file system root. That's web server specific setting. If your document root is not `e:\home\sbpsp2` then the path it generates is incorrect. Use absolute path

```
$dbName = "e:\home\sbpsp2\dados\fichas\jornada_xyz.mdb";
```